# Get column value using index dict

Tags: pandas, dictionary

I have this pandas df:

```
                      value
index1 index2 index3       
1      1      1        10.0
              2        -0.5
              3         0.0
2      2      1         3.0
              2         0.0
              3         0.0
       3      1         0.0
              2        -5.0
              3         6.0
```

I would like to get the 'value' of a specific combination of index, using a dict.

Usually, I use, for example:

```
df = df.iloc[df.index.isin([2],level='index1')]
df = df.iloc[df.index.isin([3],level='index2')]
df = df.iloc[df.index.isin([2],level='index3')]
value = df.values[0][0]
```

Now, I would like to get my value = -5 in a shorter way using this dictionary:

```
d = {'index1':2,'index2':3,'index3':2}
```

And also, if I use:

`d = {'index1':2,'index2':3}`

I would like to get the array:

`[0.0, -5.0, 6.0]`

Tips?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use SQL-like method [DataFrame.query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.query.html):

```
In [69]: df.query(' and '.join('{}=={}'.format(k,v) for k,v in d.items()))
Out[69]:
                      value
index1 index2 index3
2.0    3.0    2        -5.0
```

for another dict:

```
In [77]: d = {'index1':2,'index2':3}

In [78]: df.query(' and '.join('{}=={}'.format(k,v) for k,v in d.items()))
Out[78]:
                      value
index1 index2 index3
2.0    3.0    1         0.0
              2        -5.0
              3         6.0
```

Comment: I was so close but this is very dynamic.

Comment: Yes, general solution is only with `query`

Answer (score 0):

A non-query way would be

```
In [64]: df.loc[np.logical_and.reduce([
                 df.index.get_level_values(k) == v for k, v in d.items()])]
Out[64]:
                      value
index1 index2 index3
2      3      2        -5.0
```